# Is it possible to create a random selection of 2 arguments and in the event of a popup, the code skipped?

Tags: python, selenium

Is it possible to create a random selection of 2 arguments(with a choice of percentage of a certain argument) and in the event of a popup, the code skipped?

My code:

```
browser = uc.Chrome()
options = uc.ChromeOptions
options.headless = True

browser.get(home_url)
email_field = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, content)
email_field.click()
sleep(1)

search_login_window = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, login_windows)
search_login_window.send_keys(username)
find_place_email = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, email_login)
find_place_email.click()
sleep(2)

search_pass_window = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, password_windows)
search_pass_window.send_keys(password)
find_place_password = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, password_login)
find_place_password.click()
sleep(10)
```

Comment: what do you want to select randomly? You may use numpy functions to select randomly with some percent, or you can repeate the same element few times on list to select it with bigger percent using standard `random.choice` - ie. `random.choice(['a', 'a', 'a', 'b'])` will select `a` with `75%` (3/4) and `b` with `25%` (1/4)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand entirely what you mean since you didn't give any context in your code about where the popup would be, or what arguments you want to want to be dynamic, but here is a way to pick a random choice from a dict (which can be used as args)

```
import numpy as np

test = {"a": 1, "b": 2}

print(np.random.choice(list(test.keys()), p=[0.10, 0.90]))
```